# Find occurrences of strings in view B in column from table A

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find the occurrences of strings in view B in a string in table A. However, the performance is horrendous (takes about 17 minutes to run) and I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions to improve it.

view B has 3570 records and has one column of type varchar named MISubCode

Table A has 160081 records and has the schema in the attached image.

[image: TableBSchema]

There's also a third table, (Table C) which is largely used to filter the results of table A since I don't need to find occurrences in any of those records.

My rational to solve this was as follows:

1. Count the number of characters in the string in the desired search column in table A, producing one row for each character
2. Filter the unneeded rows using view C
3. Run each row generated in result set from 2. and use the Number column to find the occurrences from view B in the string in column from Table A until the end of the string in column from table A.

Code:

```
 SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT Number, A.StatusInputPoint_DESC, A.StatusInputPoint_CODE, A.StatusInputPoint_CORE_ID
FROM
(
SELECT Number, A.StatusInputPoint_DESC, A.StatusInputPoint_CODE,  A.StatusInputPoint_CORE_ID
FROM 
tblStatusInputPoints_CORE A
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects
) AS n(Number)
WHERE Number >= 1 AND Number <= CAST(LEN(A.StatusInputPoint_DESC) AS INT) AND System_ID = 1
) AS A
LEFT JOIN
vwAlarmLibrary_MI_StatusPoint_Mask_Match_NoWildCards C
ON
A.StatusInputPoint_CORE_ID = C.StatusInputPoint_CORE_ID
WHERE C.StatusInputPoint_CORE_ID IS NULL
) AS RemainingStatusPoints
LEFT JOIN
dbo.vwAlarmLibrary_MI_Substation_Abbreviations B
ON
SUBSTRING(RemainingStatusPoints.StatusInputPoint_DESC, Number, LEN(B.MISubCode)) = B.MISubCode
WHERE B.MISubCode IS NOT NULL
```

I'm at a loss as to how to make this faster. I tried several different methods and join combinations and I can't seem to get it to perform well. I'm not an expert in SQL Server so I don't know all the features.

I'm currently using SQL Server 2016

**EXAMPLE:**

For clarity, lets say I have these strings in view B

```
 ABC
 EFGH
 IJ
```

And I have these strings in table A

```
 123 ABC 45 IJ
 IJ
 IJ EFGH 22
```

The result should be this:

```
 Pos   String          Occurrence
 5   | 123 ABC 45 IJ | ABC
 12  | 123 ABC 45 IJ | IJ
 1   | IJ            | IJ
 1   | IJ EFGH 22    | IJ
 4   | IJ EFGH 22    | EFGH
```

Comment: So you want to take the results from a column in TableA and find all instances of these values in ViewB, or am I mis-understanding your question

Comment: No, its the other way around.

For clarity, lets say I have these strings in view B
ABC
EFGH
IJ

And I have these strings in table A
123 ABC 45 IJ
IJ
IJ EFGH 22

The result should be this:
5   | 123 ABC 45 IJ | ABC
12 | 123 ABC 45 IJ | IJ
1   | IJ                       | IJ
1   | IJ EFGH 22       | IJ
4   | IJ EFGH 22       | EFGH

Comment: Ok, so find all instances where any column in TableA contains values from a column in ViewB

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure out how to edit my question, I'll explain in better detail since comments don't preserve spacing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could just simplify this with `CHARINDEX` and `CROSS APPLY()`.  See how this method stacks up in your environment and [paste your execution plans](https://www.brentozar.come/pastetheplan/) if it happens to be slower, if you can.

To give a concrete example, create these tables:

```
declare @ViewB table (myStrings varchar(16))
insert into @ViewB
values
('ABC'),
('EFGH'),
('IJ')

declare @TableA table (colToSearch varchar(256))
insert into @TableA
values
('123 ABC 45 IJ'),
('IJ'),
('IJ EFGH 22')
```

Then this `CROSS APPLY()` query should be more efficient:

```
select
    charindex(b.myStrings,a.colToSearch) as Pos
    ,a.colToSearch as String
    ,b.myStrings as Occurance
from
    @ViewB b
cross apply (select * from @TableA) a
where
    charindex(b.myStrings,a.colToSearch) > 0
order by 
    String, charindex(b.myStrings,a.colToSearch)
```

Alternatively, you could use **`CROSS JOIN`**:

```
select
    charindex(b.myStrings,a.colToSearch) as Pos
    ,a.colToSearch as String
    ,b.myStrings as Occurance
from
    @ViewB b
cross join @TableA a
where
    charindex(b.myStrings,a.colToSearch) > 0
order by 
    String, charindex(b.myStrings,a.colToSearch)
```

### RESULTS

```
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| Pos |    String     | Occurance |
+-----+---------------+-----------+
|   5 | 123 ABC 45 IJ | ABC       |
|  12 | 123 ABC 45 IJ | IJ        |
|   1 | IJ            | IJ        |
|   1 | IJ EFGH 22    | IJ        |
|   4 | IJ EFGH 22    | EFGH      |
+-----+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Why `cross apply`?  It's a simple `cross join`.

Comment: There's no real difference here @dnoeth for that part, but instead of enumerating a row value was just make a Cartesian product to enable the use of charindex

Comment: scsimon you're a genius. This made it significantly faster using CROSS APPLY. Brought it down from 17 minutes to 50 seconds after adding in other filtering necessities from the original query to yours.

Comment: No worries @Jake I'm glad it sped it up!

Answer (score 0):

This might give you better performance

```
select B.myStrings, A.colToSearch 
     , charindex(b.myStrings,a.colToSearch) as Pos
from @ViewB as B 
join @TableA as A
  on A.colToSearch like '%'+B.myStrings+'%'
```

Comment: I've tried this. It doesn't perform any better because it has to perform a table scan that takes up most of the execution plan due to non-sargability of %x%. While CHARINDEX is also not sargable, the execution plan apparently doesn't put all the work on the table scans and instead, 70% of the cost is on the joins.

Comment: @Jake If you are searching for data inside a varchar it is going to be non-sargable.   This fix is a proper data design to address the need.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. [Sargability: Why %string% Is Slow](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/) If you use a WHERE clause LIKE 'nut%' for example, the query is considered sargable because it performs a seek instead of a scan.

Comment: @Jake Whatever, you seem to have the situation under control.